# CGContextDrawImage draws image upside down when passed UIImage.CGImage

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, cgcontextdrawimage

Does anyone know why `CGContextDrawImage` would be drawing my image upside down? I am loading an image in from my application:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testImage.png"];
```

And then simply asking core graphics to draw it to my context:

```
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 145, 15), image.CGImage);
```

It renders in the right place, and dimensions, but the image is upside down. I must be missing something really obvious here?

Answer (score 250, accepted):

Instead of

```
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 145, 15), image.CGImage);
```

Use

```
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 145, 15)];
```

In the middle of your begin/end `CGcontext` methods.

This will draw the image with the correct orientation into your current image context - I'm pretty sure this has something to do with the `UIImage` holding onto knowledge of the orientation while the `CGContextDrawImage` method gets the underlying raw image data with no understanding of orientation.

Comment: This solution doesn't allow you to use CG functions on your image, such as CGContextSetAlpha(), whereas the 2nd answer does.

Comment: Good point, though mostly you don't need custom alpha levels for drawing an image (typically those are baked into images ahead of time for things that need alpha).  Basically my motto is, use a little code as you can because more code means more chances for bugs.

Comment: Hi, What do you mean by in the middle of your begin/end CGContext methods, can you give me more sample code. I am trying with storing the context somewhere and use the context to draw the image in

Comment: You shouldn't store the context, use UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() to get a context you can pass to that method.  There's also a UIGraphicsBeginImageContext and UIGraphicsEndImageContext pair of methods that you use when you are drawing into a custom image, instead of the current context.

Comment: While it might work for Rusty, -[UIImage drawInRect:] has the problem that it's not thread-safe.  For my particular application, that's why I'm using CGContextDrawImage() in the first place.

Comment: Olie, can you elaborate on / provide a reference for drawInRect's lack of thread-safety?

Comment: Apple states in the UIKit docs that you should call UI methods on the main thread - that includes the drawing methods...

Comment: Just to clarify: Core Graphics is built onto OS X where the coordinate system is upside down compared to iOS (y starting at the lower left hand side in OS X). That's why Core Graphics draws the image upside down whereas drawInRect handles this for you

Answer (score 218):

Even after applying everything I have mentioned, I've still had dramas with the images.  In the end, i've just used Gimp to create a 'flipped vertical' version of all my images.  Now I don't need to use any Transforms.  Hopefully this won't cause further problems down the track.

> Does anyone know why
>   CGContextDrawImage would be drawing my
>   image upside down? I am loading an
>   image in from my application:

Quartz2d uses a different co-ordinate system, where the origin is in the lower left corner.  So when Quartz draws pixel x[5], y[10] of a 100 * 100 image, that pixel is being drawn in the lower left corner instead of the upper left.  Thus causing the 'flipped' image.

The x co-ordinate system matches, so you will need to flip the y co-ordinates.

```
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, image.size.height);
```

This means we have translated the image by 0 units on the x axis and by the images height on the y axis.  However, this alone will mean our image is still upside down, just being drawn "image.size.height" below where we wish it to be drawn.

The Quartz2D programming guide recommends using ScaleCTM and passing negative values to flip the image.  You can use the following code to do this -

```
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
```

Combine the two just before your `CGContextDrawImage` call and you should have the image drawn correctly.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testImage.png"];    
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);       

CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, image.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

CGContextDrawImage(context, imageRect, image.CGImage);
```

Just be careful if your imageRect co-ordinates do not match those of your image, as you can get unintended results.

To convert back the coordinates:

```
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -imageRect.size.height);
```

Comment: this is good but i found that other stuff was being influenced by the translate and scale even when i tried setting back to 0,0 and 1.0,1.0 I went with Kendall's solution in the end but i realise this that is using UIImage rather than the lower level CGImage stuff that we are working with here

Comment: If you are using drawLayer and want to draw a CGImageRef into the context, this technique here is just want the doctor ordered! If have the rect for the image, then CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, image.size.height + image.origin.y), then set the rect.origin.y to 0 before CGContextDrawImage(). Thanks!

Comment: I had issues once with ImageMagick where the iPhone camera resulted in incorrect orientation. It turns out it's do the the orientation flag in the image file, so portrait images were, say 960px x 640px  with the flag set to "left" - as in the left side is the top (or something close to that).  This thread might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260249/resizing-uiimages-pulled-from-the-camera-also-rotates-the-uiimage

Comment: Why don't you use `CGContextSaveGState()` and `CGContextRestoreGState()` to save and restore the transformation matrix?

Answer (score 21):

Best of both worlds, use UIImage's `drawAtPoint:` or `drawInRect:` while still specifying your custom context:

```
UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
[image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero]; // UIImage will handle all especial cases!
UIGraphicsPopContext();
```

Also you avoid modifying your context with `CGContextTranslateCTM` or `CGContextScaleCTM` which the second answer does.

Comment: This is a great idea, but for me it resulted in an image that was both upside down and left to right. I'm guessing that results will vary from image to image.

Comment: Maybe this stopped working with later iOS releases? At the time it worked with everything for me.

Comment: I think it was actually down to how I was creating the context. Once I started using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` instead of just initing a new `CGContext`, it seemed to work.

Answer (score 13):

I use this **Swift 5**, pure **Core Graphics** extension that correctly handles non-zero origins in image rects:

```
extension CGContext {

    /// Draw `image` flipped vertically, positioned and scaled inside `rect`.
    public func drawFlipped(_ image: CGImage, in rect: CGRect) {
        self.saveGState()
        self.translateBy(x: 0, y: rect.origin.y + rect.height)
        self.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        self.draw(image, in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: rect.origin.x, y: 0), size: rect.size))
        self.restoreGState()
    }
}
```

You can use it exactly like `CGContext`'s regular `draw(: in:)` method:

```
ctx.drawFlipped(myImage, in: myRect)
```

Answer (score 12):

Relevant Quartz2D docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH14-SW4

> **Flipping the Default Coordinate System**
>
> Flipping in UIKit drawing modifies the backing CALayer to align a drawing environment having a LLO coordinate system with the default coordinate system of UIKit. If you only use UIKit methods and function for drawing, you shouldn’t need to flip the CTM. However, if you mix Core Graphics or Image I/O function calls with UIKit calls, flipping the CTM might be necessary.
>
> Specifically, if you draw an image or PDF document by calling Core Graphics functions directly, the object is rendered upside-down in the view’s context. You must flip the CTM to display the image and pages correctly.
>
> To flip a object drawn to a Core Graphics context so that it appears correctly when displayed in a UIKit view, you must modify the CTM in two steps. You translate the origin to the upper-left corner of the drawing area, and then you apply a scale translation, modifying the y-coordinate by -1. The code for doing this looks similar to the following:

```
CGContextSaveGState(graphicsContext);
CGContextTranslateCTM(graphicsContext, 0.0, imageHeight);
CGContextScaleCTM(graphicsContext, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextDrawImage(graphicsContext, image, CGRectMake(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight));
CGContextRestoreGState(graphicsContext);
```

Answer (score 10):

If anyone is interested in a no-brainer solution for drawing an image in a custom rect in a context:

```
 func drawImage(image: UIImage, inRect rect: CGRect, context: CGContext!) {

    //flip coords
    let ty: CGFloat = (rect.origin.y + rect.size.height)
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, ty)
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0)

    //draw image
    let rect__y_zero = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: rect.origin.x, y:0), size: rect.size)
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect__y_zero, image.CGImage)

    //flip back
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0)
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -ty)

}
```

The image will be scaled to fill the rect.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure for `UIImage`, but this kind of behaviour usually occurs when coordinates are flipped. Most of OS X coordinate systems have their origin at the lower left corner, as in Postscript and PDF. But `CGImage` coordinate system has its origin at the upper left corner.

Possible solutions may involve an `isFlipped` property or a `scaleYBy:-1` affine transform.

Answer (score 4):

It happens because QuartzCore has the coordinate system "bottom-left", while UIKit – "top-left".

In the case you can extend **CGContext**:

```
extension CGContext {
  func changeToTopLeftCoordinateSystem() {
    translateBy(x: 0, y: boundingBoxOfClipPath.size.height)
    scaleBy(x: 1, y: -1)
  }
}

// somewhere in render 
ctx.saveGState()
ctx.changeToTopLeftCoordinateSystem()
ctx.draw(cgImage!, in: frame)
```

Comment: This is super useful, works with the new UIGraphicsImageRenderer!

Answer (score 3):

`UIImage` contains a `CGImage` as its main content member as well as scaling and orientation factors. Since `CGImage` and its various functions are derived from OSX, it expects a coordinate system that is upside down compared to the iPhone. When you create a `UIImage`, it defaults to an upside-down orientation to compensate (you can change this!). Use the .`CGImage` property to access the very powerful `CGImage` functions, but drawing onto the iPhone screen etc. is best done with the `UIImage` methods.

Comment: how do you change default upside - down orientation of UIImage?

Answer (score 3):

**Supplemental answer with Swift code**

Quartz 2D graphics use a coordinate system with the origin in the bottom left while UIKit in iOS uses a coordinate system with the origin at the top left. Everything usually works fine but when doing some graphics operations, you have to modify the coordinate system yourself. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_overview/dq_overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH202-CJBBAEEC) states:

> Some technologies set up their graphics contexts using a different
>   default coordinate system than the one used by Quartz. Relative to
>   Quartz, such a coordinate system is a modified coordinate system and
>   must be compensated for when performing some Quartz drawing
>   operations. The most common modified coordinate system places the
>   origin in the upper-left corner of the context and changes the y-axis
>   to point towards the bottom of the page.

This phenomenon can be seen in the following two instances of custom views that draw an image in their `drawRect` methods.

[image]

On the left side, the image is upside-down and on the right side the coordinate system has been translated and scaled so that the origin is in the top left.

**Upside-down image**

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    // image
    let image = UIImage(named: "rocket")!
    let imageRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)

    // context
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    // draw image in context
    CGContextDrawImage(context, imageRect, image.CGImage)

}
```

**Modified coordinate system**

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    // image
    let image = UIImage(named: "rocket")!
    let imageRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)

    // context
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    // save the context so that it can be undone later
    CGContextSaveGState(context)

    // put the origin of the coordinate system at the top left
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, image.size.height)
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0)

    // draw the image in the context
    CGContextDrawImage(context, imageRect, image.CGImage)

    // undo changes to the context
    CGContextRestoreGState(context)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

***Swift 3.0 & 4.0***

```
yourImage.draw(in: CGRect, blendMode: CGBlendMode, alpha: ImageOpacity)
```

No Alteration needed

Answer (score 1):

`drawInRect` is certainly the way to go.  Here's another little thing that will come in way useful when doing this.  Usually the picture and the rectangle into which it is going to go don't conform.  In that case `drawInRect` will stretch the picture.  Here's a quick and cool way to make sure that the picture's aspect ration isn't changed, by reversing the transformation (which will be to fit the whole thing in):

```
//Picture and irect don't conform, so there'll be stretching, compensate
    float xf = Picture.size.width/irect.size.width;
    float yf = Picture.size.height/irect.size.height;
    float m = MIN(xf, yf);
    xf /= m;
    yf /= m;
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, xf, yf);

    [Picture drawInRect: irect];
```

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this problem using the same function:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);

UIGraphicsPushContext(context);

[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(gestureEndPoint.x,gestureEndPoint.y,350,92)];

UIGraphicsPopContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3 CoreGraphics Solution**

If you want to use CG for whatever your reason might be, instead of UIImage, this Swift 3 construction based on previous answers did solve the issue for me:

```
if let cgImage = uiImage.cgImage {
    cgContext.saveGState()
    cgContext.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: cgRect.size.height)
    cgContext.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
    cgContext.draw(cgImage, in: cgRect)
    cgContext.restoreGState()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

During the course of my project I jumped from [Kendall's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/522091/1338292) to [Cliff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/511199/1338292) to solve this problem for images that are loaded from the phone itself.

In the end I ended up using [`CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider) instead:

```
NSString* imageFileName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"clockdial.png"];

return CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename([imageFileName UTF8String]), NULL, YES, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
```

This doesn't suffer from the orientation issues that you would get from getting the `CGImage` from a `UIImage` and it can be used as the contents of a `CALayer` without a hitch.

Answer (score 0):

```
func renderImage(size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size).image { rendererContext in
        // flip y axis
        rendererContext.cgContext.translateBy(x: 0, y: size.height)
        rendererContext.cgContext.scaleBy(x: 1, y: -1)

        // draw image rotated/offsetted
        rendererContext.cgContext.saveGState()
        rendererContext.cgContext.translateBy(x: translate.x, y: translate.y)
        rendererContext.cgContext.rotate(by: rotateRadians)
        rendererContext.cgContext.draw(cgImage, in: drawRect)
        rendererContext.cgContext.restoreGState()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5 answer** based on @ZpaceZombor's excellent answer

If you have a UIImage, just use

```
var image: UIImage = .... 
image.draw(in: CGRect)
```

If you have a CGImage use my category below

Note: Unlike some other answers, this one takes into account that the rect you want to draw in might have y != 0. Those answers that don't take that into account are incorrect and won't work in the general case.

```
extension CGContext {
    final func drawImage(image: CGImage, inRect rect: CGRect) {

        //flip coords
        let ty: CGFloat = (rect.origin.y + rect.size.height)
        translateBy(x: 0, y: ty)
        scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

        //draw image
        let rect__y_zero = CGRect(x: rect.origin.x, y: 0, width: rect.width, height: rect.height)
        draw(image, in: rect__y_zero)

        //flip back
        scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        translateBy(x: 0, y: -ty)

    }
}
```

Use like this:

```
let imageFrame: CGRect = ...
let context: CGContext = ....
let img: CGImage = ..... 
context.drawImage(image: img, inRect: imageFrame)
```

Comment: This is almost a perfect solution, but consider changing the function to draw(image: UIImage, inRect rect:CGRect) and handle uiImage.cgimage inside the method

Answer (score -5):

You can also solve this problem by doing this:

```
//Using an Image as a mask by directly inserting UIImageObject.CGImage causes
//the same inverted display problem. This is solved by saving it to a CGImageRef first.

//CGImageRef image = [UImageObject CGImage];

//CGContextDrawImage(context, boundsRect, image);

Nevermind... Stupid caching.
```