# Resizing UIimages pulled from the Camera also ROTATES the UIimage?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I am getting UIimages from the camera and assigning them to UIImageViews to be displayed. When I do this the camera gives me a 1200 x 1600 pixel image which I then assign to a UIImageView in my Application. The image is displayed as expected in the image view under this condition. However, when I attempt to RESIZE the retrieved UIImage before assigning it to the UIImageView, the image is resizing as expected but there IS a problem in that somewhere (in the RESIZING code?) my UIImage is getting ROTATED... As a result, when I assign the resized UIImage to a UIImageView the image is rotated 90 degrees and appears stretched as the aspect ratio (1200 x 1600 pixels) was unchanged...

**I am using this to get a UIImage from the Camera:**

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
{

        myImg = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
        myResizedImg = [self resizeImage:myImg width:400 height:533];
        [myImageView setImage:myResizedImg];

}
```

**I am using this to resize it:**

```
-(UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)anImage width:(int)width height:(int)height
{

    CGImageRef imageRef = [anImage CGImage];

    CGImageAlphaInfo alphaInfo = CGImageGetAlphaInfo(imageRef);

    if (alphaInfo == kCGImageAlphaNone)
    alphaInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;


    CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), 4 * width, CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef), alphaInfo);

    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);

    CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];

    CGContextRelease(bitmap);
    CGImageRelease(ref);

    return result;  
}
```

**QUESTION: How do I RESIZE a UIImage pulled from the Camera WITHOUT rotating the pixels?**

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is because the imageOrientation on the code that you have is not being taken into account. Specifically, if the imageOrientation is right/left, then you need to both rotate the image and swap width/height. Here is some code to do this:

```
-(UIImage*)imageByScalingToSize:(CGSize)targetSize
{
    UIImage* sourceImage = self; 
    CGFloat targetWidth = targetSize.width;
    CGFloat targetHeight = targetSize.height;

    CGImageRef imageRef = [sourceImage CGImage];
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceInfo = CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef);

    if (bitmapInfo == kCGImageAlphaNone) {
        bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;
    }

    CGContextRef bitmap;

    if (sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp || sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
        bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, targetWidth, targetHeight, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef), colorSpaceInfo, bitmapInfo);

    } else {
        bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, targetHeight, targetWidth, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef), colorSpaceInfo, bitmapInfo);

    }   

    if (sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, radians(90));
        CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, 0, -targetHeight);

    } else if (sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, radians(-90));
        CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, -targetWidth, 0);

    } else if (sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {
        // NOTHING
    } else if (sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
        CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, targetWidth, targetHeight);
        CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, radians(-180.));
    }

    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight), imageRef);
    CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
    UIImage* newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];

    CGContextRelease(bitmap);
    CGImageRelease(ref);

    return newImage; 
}
```

This will resize your image and rotate it to the correct orientation. If you need the definition for radians, it is:

```
static inline double radians (double degrees) {return degrees * M_PI/180;}
```

The answer Daniel gave is also correct, but it suffers from the problem that it is not thread-safe, since you're using UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(). Since the above code only uses CG functions, you're all set. I also have a similar function to resize and do proper aspect fill on images - let me know if that's what you're looking for.

Note: I got the original function from [this post](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/7307-resizing-photo-new-uiimage.html), and did some modifications to make it work on JPEGs.

Comment: how can i use this code to fix orientation and then rotate to spec. degreeses?

Comment: This code didn't seem to work for me; seems like the issue is that the photos treat the "up" orientation as matching a landscape photo taken with the home button on the right, while this code treats "up" as matching portrait.

Answer (score 12):

I had this problem too with some of the code out there, i found this code that works, check it out, let me know what you find

```
+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image 
               scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
{
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
   [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
   UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   return newImage;
}
```

Comment: this code does not take the camera orientation into account. it simply scales the image to the specified size.

Comment: no, but you can easily query for orientation and send the appropriate sizes in there...

Comment: The orientation of `newImage` is always `UIImageOrientationUp` no matter what the orientation of `image` is, but the code is right, because `drawInRect:` take the orientation into account and make proper rotation inside.

Comment: This is also the method i use. The CGContextDrawImage call does not draw in proper orientation. The drawInRect call does. This saves all the work by using the call already designed for it.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3**

I add this to `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method and then use `image` without worrying for its rotation.

```
var image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
if (image.imageOrientation != .up) {
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, false, image.scale)
  image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height))
  image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a square image from a rectangle image (no matter horizontal or vertical) by cropping it by width or height in both sides, use my code. The difference is that I don't stretch, but I crop. I made it from the top code by modification:

```
//Cropping _image to fit it to the square by height or width

CGFloat a = _image.size.height;
CGFloat b = _image.size.width;
CGRect cropRect;

if (!(a==b)) {
    if (a<b) {
        cropRect = CGRectMake((b-a)/2.0, 0, a, a);
        b = a;
    }
    else if (b<a) {
        cropRect = CGRectMake(0, (a-b)/2.0, b, b);
        a = b;
    }

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([_image CGImage], cropRect);

    UIImage* sourceImage = _image; 
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceInfo = CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef);
    CGContextRef bitmap;
    if (sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp || sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
        bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, a, a, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef), colorSpaceInfo, bitmapInfo);

    } else {
        bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, a, a, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef), colorSpaceInfo, bitmapInfo);
    }

    if (sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, radians(90));
        CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, 0, -a);

    } else if (sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, radians(-90));
        CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, -a, 0);

    } else if (sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {
        // NOTHING
    } else if (sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
        CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, a, a);
        CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, radians(-180.));
    }

    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(0, 0, a, a), imageRef);
    CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
    _image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
}
```