# resize image with aspect ratio

Tags: iphone, image, cgbitmapcontextcreate

I try to resize image with aspect ratio, like done in the following links

[Resizing UIimages pulled from the Camera also ROTATES the UIimage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260249/resizing-uiimages-pulled-from-the-camera-also-rotates-the-uiimage/1262395#1262395)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282830/uiimagepickercontroller-uiimage-memory-and-more

This works fine on the simulator. But on my iPhone-4 I get a black block on the right side of the picture. (a 4th of the picture is black). It only happens for pictures which have imageOrientation right...so far. ImageOrientation up doesn't give any problems.

Somehow I have the feeling that CGBitmapContextCreate is giving the problem. I already removed CGImageGetBytesPerRow, because this doesn't work as I have read. At the moment I have the following code:

```
if (sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp || sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, targetWidth, targetHeight, 8, 4*targetWidth, colorSpaceInfo, bitmapInfo);
} else {
bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, targetHeight, targetWidth, 8, 4*targetHeight, colorSpaceInfo, bitmapInfo);
}
```

What could case these problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the category files on this site to resize UIImages:

http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

Comment: Thanks, this works very good. Also thanks for the amazingly fast reply.