# Why my image is up side down?

Tags: objective-c, image

This is my drawInContext method:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myImage" ofType:@"png"]];
CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 175, 175);
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([img CGImage], cropRect);

CGRect imageRect;

imageRect.origin = CGPointMake(0, 0);
imageRect.size = CGSizeMake(175, 175);

CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), imageRect, imageRef);
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

My image is upside down, how can I change it? What's wrong with my code? How can I change the image become normal?? thx .

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506622/cgcontextdrawimage-draws-image-upside-down-when-passed-uiimage-cgimage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), imageRect, imageRef);
```

do this:

```
[img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 175, 175)]
```

CGContextDrawImage doesn't preserve orientation.