# How to implement highlighting on UIImage like UIButton does when tapped?

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, uibutton, mask, layer

I need to replicate the effect that the UIButton does on an image when tapped, the highlighting. See:

[image]

The original PNG is a square with alpha background. When I set it as UIButton's image it automatically apply an effect on the non-alpha pixels of the image.

How to do this effect?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You could achieve this with a simple category on UIImage:

```
@interface UIImage (Tint)

- (UIImage *)tintedImageUsingColor:(UIColor *)tintColor;

@end

@implementation UIImage (Tint)

- (UIImage *)tintedImageUsingColor:(UIColor *)tintColor {
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, self.scale);
  CGRect drawRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height);
  [self drawInRect:drawRect];
  [tintColor set];
  UIRectFillUsingBlendMode(drawRect, kCGBlendModeSourceAtop);
  UIImage *tintedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  return tintedImage;
}

@end
```

For the effect shown above, you'd pass something like `[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.3]` as the tintColor parameter (experiment with the alpha value).

Comment: Unlike some other solutions floating around SO, this has the nice effect of not coloring the whole rect. Good use of UIRectFillUsingBlendMode()

Comment: Awesome. Finally found an answer to this. :) Thank you!

Comment: For RETINA display support:
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);

Comment: Using `self.scale` would be better here.