# Create adjusted image similar to UIButton's adjustsImageWhenHighlighted effect

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-graphics

I'm working with some data icons in table view. And sometimes my icons is in disabled state. I want to try create grayed versions of my icons programmatically, before I ask designer to do that for me.
Similar adjustment happens in UIButton when image auto-adjusted for highlighted state. Does anyone know how to do that image adjustment?

Answer (score 0):

What about just modifying the alpha of the icons?

If you make the images partly transparent you'll get a similar effect and no extra programming is needed.

Another possibility is to add a partially transparent gray UIImageView over the button. The button will essentially be made gray-looking -- you'll need the UIImageView to have an alpha of about .2, or somewhere in that range.

Comment: image become less visible instead gray-and-white. i think i need some way with extra programming. :)

Comment: @EvgenBodunov Can you supply images of what you want before and after? Being lazy, I would look for the simplest way to do it. (See my edited answer.)

Comment: I found a good answer at http://stackoverflow.com/q/4681903/241482 Thanks for your help anyway.