# How to emulate the timing of highlighting the background image on a UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I've created a custom button because I wanted to be able to compose it of multiple different images. It actually subclasses UIControl instead of UIButton. This led to the issue of highlighting the images while it was being tapped.

So, I followed the advice in this question by creating a category on UIImage to emulate the highlighting of a standard UIButton: [How to implement highlighting on UIImage like UIButton does when tapped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681903/how-to-implement-highlighting-on-uiimage-like-uibutton-does-when-tapped)

I'm triggering the image tinting based on the UIControlEventTouchDown, UIControlEventTouchUpInside, and UIControlEventTouchUpOutside events.

This *mostly* works, except the timing is a bit off. With a standard UIButton, no matter how long or short the user taps down, the highlighting always happens, but with my implementation, if the user taps very quickly (which is most times), the highlighting doesn't happen.

I'm assuming this may be because the screen isn't getting re-drawn between the time the user taps down and up, but I'm not totally sure.

What I've tried:

- Calling `setNeedsDisplay` right after swapping out the image - doesn't help
- Over-riding `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` and putting the image swapping code there - doesn't help
- Executing the image swapping code asynchronously inside a `dispatch_async` call - doesn't help

At this point, the only other thing I can think of is to set up a timer that manually fires off the image change after a slight delay if it detects that the user hasn't pressed down for longer than a certain time period.

This feels wrong, and I'm wondering if there's a better way to achieve this. Is there some other event I should be over-riding?