# Multiply image and color

Tags: ios

I have an image with transparence background, for example [image](http://gyazo.com/a450dd290f8ff5f7ebfda0de68375c7b.png).

I need to create many images with different color and I want to use this one image and multiply it with color for create some other images, for example [new image](http://gyazo.com/d3998c97c7a84f33bbb01ac4c5989561.png).

Could you please help me with some lines of code. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tint a transparent PNG image in iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514066/how-to-tint-a-transparent-png-image-in-iphone)

Comment: Please check for existing answers before you ask a new question. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help:

```
UIImage *beginUIImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];

CIImage *beginImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:beginUIImage.CGImage];    

CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISepiaTone" 
                              keysAndValues: kCIInputImageKey, beginImage, 
                    @"inputIntensity", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8], nil];

CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];    

UIImage *endImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCIImage:outputImage];
```

The `beginUIImage` is the initial transparent image. Then I change it into a CIImage to ease the process of applying filters. Then I apply a Sepia filter to the image. Then I output the image with a filter applied into another CIImage called `outputImage`. Lastly, I change the `outputImage` into a UIImage to be used later, perhaps put into a UIImageView, perhaps saved into the Photo library. You can change the type of filter to change the output images' colors.