# Drawing a UIButton/UIBarButtonItem to use parent bar's tintColor?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-graphics, uibarbuttonitem

I've got a bit of a dilemma. It's not a dealbreaker, but I'm interested in a decent answer if there is one.

I've been using a `UIButton` with a custom subview inside of a `UIBarButtonItem` (as the bar button item's `customView`). My custom subview is *not* a `UILabel` nor is it a `UIImage`, which is why I'm doing what I'm doing. This `UIBarButtonItem` is an item on my navigation bar, and the navigation bar has a `tintColor` set. I want the `UIButton` to have that rounded-rect appearance of `UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered`, which means it should also take on the `tintColor` of its parent bar.

Current solutions out there have implemented extracting `png` files from UIKit for `UINavigationBarDefaultButton.png` and family. This would look *great* if I weren't setting a `tintColor` property; instead the button remains that "iOS navy blue", when I want, say, bright orange (not the color I'm using but you get my drift). Which brings me to my dilemma: what's the best way to make a UIButton look and act like that `UIBarButtonItem` style, *including* taking on the `tintColor` property? I can set that property myself on the button; it's no big deal.

Would I want to draw that `UIButton`'s background in CoreGraphics? Is there a framework/library out there that implements this already? If I'm dreaming the impossible, just tell me. I'm not that awesome with doing CoreGraphics by hand yet, but it's definitely not outside the realm of possibility.

If this can't be done, I know I can always take the cool custom `UIView` I'm attempting to finagle in and just save it off as an image (and thus use `UIImage` inside of a `UIBarButtonItem`), but I'd like to see if this is possible.

This is what I'm dealing with (below). The back button looks awesome, but only because I'm not messing with it. I'd like that `rightBarButtonItem` to use my `tintColor` that I have set, but in order to give it that `UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered` appearance with a `customView` set, I'm forced to make the button use `png` files for its background. Below is what you see, even with `tintColor` set on the `UIBarButtonItem` (since it's using a `png`).

[image: uinavigationbar]

Comment: Just call `[super tintColor]`.

Comment: `[super tintColor]` doesn't seem to work; see my revisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7377827/194869) on Stack Overflow, that gets me close enough that I can wing the rest. It's a well-detailed post about how to tint a `UIImage` with a `UIColor`; I've pulled it out into a function and I've posted a gist for that [right here](https://gist.github.com/4313707).

Combined with that, I've defined a category method on `UIButton` that lets me create a button with that background image, tinted, and I plop that into an empty `UIBarButtonItem`.

```
+ (id)buttonWithBarStyleAndTintColor:(UIColor *)tintColor customView:(UIView *)customView {
    UIImage *defaultNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"UINavigationBarDefaultButton.png"];
    UIImage *defaultPressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"UINavigationBarDefaultButtonPressed.png"];
    UIImage *back = [TintImageWithTintColor(defaultNormal, tintColor)
                     stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5.0
                     topCapHeight:0.0];
    UIImage *pressed = [TintImageWithTintColor(defaultPressed, tintColor)
                        stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5.0
                        topCapHeight:0.0];

    UIButton *button = [self buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 34.0f, 30.0f);
    [button addSubview:customView];
    customView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    customView.frame = CGRectCenterRectInRect(customView.frame, button.frame);
    [button setBackgroundImage:back forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage:pressed forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [button setBackgroundImage:pressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    return button;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try and set the UIButton type to custom and make sure its color is clear, same for your custom view, that way the only visible view will be the UIBarButtonItem tint color.

Also if you are willing to invest, there is this tool called PaintCode that does the code for CoreGraphics for you.

Comment: I may give PaintCode a shot, seems slick. Your answer doesn't help me much, though, as making sure my button and custom views have clear backgrounds and setting the tint color on my `UIBarButtonItem` just shows my custom view (the globe) by itself on the toolbar, and not the surrounding chrome.