# tintColor of UIButton's ImageView is not changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uibutton

How to change `tintColor` of `button.imageView`. If I use the same image in `UIImageView` with the same rendering mode as below the `tintColor` will change but the same is not happening for button's image view. Is it because of buttonType ?

```
    UIButton *frontButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [frontButton setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:FRONT_IMAGE] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [frontButton.imageView setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self addSubview:frontButton];
```

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511639/how-to-tint-the-background-images-of-an-uibutton-programmatically-and-dynamicall) hope this link help you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set Button type "System" and then set tint color.
This solution will definitely work. Please try this

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
 [btn setTintColor:YOUR_COLOR];
 [btn setImage:YOUR_Image];
```

Comment: Can I use [btn setBackgroundImage:Your_Image]; ?

Comment: is there any difference in both?

Comment: OK, Got the differences.

Answer (score 2):

Try This code to change the tint color inside Button :

```
UIButton *frontButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
UIImageView *imageV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:FRONT_IMAGE]];
imageV.image = [imageV.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
imageV.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
[frontButton setImage:imageV.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 2):

`Swift 4.0`

```swift
extension UIImage {
    public static func imageWithRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate(named: String) -> UIImage? {
        let image = UIImage(named: named)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        return imageView.image
    }
}
```

Using

```swift
let button = UIButton.setImage(UIImage.imageWithRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate(named: ""), for: .normal)
button.tintColor = .red
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like,

```
UIButton *frontButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[frontButton setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:FRONT_IMAGE] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[frontButton setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self addSubview:frontButton];
```

Set tint color to button and if image rendering mode is template then it will also get this tint color.

If you want different tint color for button and different for image then you should take one temporary imageview and set image to that imageview with rendering mode template and then set tint color to that imageview and then set image to button from that imageview.

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I just need to give `tintColor` to `UIButton` not to button's `imageView` property after setting the rendering mode as mentioned in the question.

```
[button setTintColor:YOUR_COLOR];
```

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin iOs Solution:

```
  var image = uiButton.ImageView.Image.ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate);
  uiButton.SetImage(image, UIControlState.Normal);
  uiButton.TintColor = effect.TintColor.ToUIColor();
```

Comment: Awesome, I was looking for this. Regards