# Set tint color in UIButton's background image

Tags: ios, swift

The answers here a from objective c which I can not read: [How to tint the background images of an UIButton programmatically and dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511639/how-to-tint-the-background-images-of-an-uibutton-programmatically-and-dynamicall)

I am curious if there is a way to apply a tint color to an UIButton's background image. For the UIButton and the imageView itself it is easy. The background image does however not have the option tintColor.

Comment: check https://gist.github.com/alexruperez/90f44545b57c25b977c4

Comment: *from objective c which I can not read* Did you even try? The accepted answer is mostly straight C calls to Core Graphics. And it really doesn't take much imagination to look at a name like `setTintColor:` in Objective-C code and find [the corresponding thing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624025-tintcolor) in the UIKit Swift documentation.