# How to color-tint the white background of an image in iOS

Tags: ios, tint

I am porting a card-melding-game from Android to iOS (see https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pipperpublishing.fivekings). I want to tint the wild cards in yellow (as an aid to game play for novices).

In Android this is brainlessly easy, using cards with black on white.

```
    static final int TINT_COLOR = Color.parseColor("#FFFF66"); //light yellow
    static final PorterDuff.Mode PORTER_DUFF_MODE = PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN;
...

        if (highlightWildCard != null) {
            //mutate so this setting will not carry through to other rounds or to the Computer cards when shown
            this.getDrawable().mutate();
            this.getDrawable().setColorFilter(TINT_COLOR, PORTER_DUFF_MODE);
        }
```

I can't find an equivalent way to do this in iOS. I have tried this:

```
class CardView : UIImageView {
        static let TINT_COLOR = UIColor.yellowColor() //FIXME: UIColorFromRGB(0xFFFF66); //light yellow
...
        if (highlightWildCard != nil) {
            //for tintColor to be applied, have to replace with an image template - note this creates a new image
            self.image = self.image!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
            self.backgroundColor = CardView.TINT_COLOR
        }
```

but this just paints the whole card yellow.

And I have tried using CGContextSetBlendMode, but just got a bunch of errors that I didn't understand.

Hopefully you iOS experts can point me in the right direction (and hopefully not one involving creating a separate set of tinted cards ;)

UPDATE: I have tried using this excellent extension from this post:
[How to tint a transparent PNG image in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514066/how-to-tint-a-transparent-png-image-in-iphone)
but this seems to leave the card untinted.

Comment: Have you tried `self.tintColor = CardView.TINT_COLOR`?

Comment: Yes, that colors the whole card yellow :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CoreImage` framework for that.

I can show you how to do it in Objective-C, so I hope this helps. You should be able to translate it to swift, or you can just use it directly using a bridging header.

First you'll need a to create a `CoreImage` context. It is best to initialize it once - so save a reference to it with a property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) CIContext *ciContext;
...
self.ciContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:@{kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer : @NO}];
```

Now the interesting part - using a `CIColorMatrix` filter to shift the white. Here's a method which does just that (notice it uses the ciContext we've previously created):

```
-(UIImage*)filteredImageFromImage:(UIImage*)sourceImage withColor:(UIColor*)color
{
    size_t componentCount = CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(color.CGColor);
    if (componentCount < 4)
    {
        return sourceImage;
    }

    CIImage *inputCIImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:sourceImage.CGImage];
    CGRect extent = [inputCIImage extent];

    CGFloat r, g, b, a;
    [color getRed:&r green:&g blue:&b alpha:&a];

    CIFilter *colorMatrixFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMatrix"];
    [colorMatrixFilter setDefaults];
    [colorMatrixFilter setValue:inputCIImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    [colorMatrixFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:r Y:0 Z:0 W:0] forKey:@"inputRVector"];
    [colorMatrixFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:g Z:0 W:0] forKey:@"inputGVector"];
    [colorMatrixFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:0 Z:b W:0] forKey:@"inputBVector"];

    CGImageRef cgiimage = [self.ciContext createCGImage:colorMatrixFilter.outputImage fromRect:extent];
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgiimage scale:[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] orientation:sourceImage.imageOrientation];
    CGImageRelease(cgiimage);

    return newImage;
}
```

Finally, to tint your card to yellow:

```
UIImage *cardImage = [self filteredImageFromImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"card"] withColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
```

**Edit:**

Here's how to use it in swift with a bridging header:

1. Add a new Objective-C class. Let's call it ImageFilter.

The header file:

```
// ImageFilter.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 

@interface ImageFilter : NSObject
-(UIImage*)filteredImageFromImage:(UIImage*)sourceImage withColor:(UIColor*)color;
@end
```

The implementation file:

```
// ImageFilter.m

#import "ImageFilter.h"
#import <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>


@interface ImageFilter()
@property (strong, nonatomic) CIContext *ciContext;
@end

@implementation ImageFilter

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        self.ciContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:@{kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer : @NO}];
    }
    return self;
}

-(UIImage*)filteredImageFromImage:(UIImage*)sourceImage withColor:(UIColor*)color
{
    size_t componentCount = CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(color.CGColor);
    if (componentCount < 4)
    {
        return sourceImage;
    }

    CIImage *inputCIImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:sourceImage.CGImage];
    CGRect extent = [inputCIImage extent];

    CGFloat r, g, b, a;
    [color getRed:&r green:&g blue:&b alpha:&a];

    CIFilter *colorMatrixFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMatrix"];
    [colorMatrixFilter setDefaults];
    [colorMatrixFilter setValue:inputCIImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    [colorMatrixFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:r Y:0 Z:0 W:0] forKey:@"inputRVector"];
    [colorMatrixFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:g Z:0 W:0] forKey:@"inputGVector"];
    [colorMatrixFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:0 Z:b W:0] forKey:@"inputBVector"];

    CGImageRef cgiimage = [self.ciContext createCGImage:colorMatrixFilter.outputImage fromRect:extent];
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgiimage scale:[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] orientation:sourceImage.imageOrientation];
    CGImageRelease(cgiimage);

    return newImage;
}

@end
```

2. In your bridging file (usually YourProject-Bridging-Header.h which Xcode will ask and create automatically when you add a new Objective-C file to your project) import our new file:

   `#import ImageEffect.h`

Also, don't forget to make sure the "YourProject-Bridging-Header.h" is specified under "Objective-C Bridging Header in your target's build settings.

3. Use it in your swift code:

   let imageFilter: ImageFilter = ImageFilter()

   ```
   let cardImage = imageFilter.filteredImageFromImage(UIImage(named: "card"), withColor: UIColor.yellowColor());
   ```

Note: the code formatting went a bit crazy on me, don't know why. It's causing the last bit of code in swift to not show as a code block properly...

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try!

Comment: This crashed on me, although admittedly that might be because of my imperfect conversion to Swift. However, I was able to get the other solution working (see above)

Comment: @Opus1217 yes, probably some conversion issues, this bit of code works just fine. At least you got another working solution..

Comment: I'll give youe solution another try since the tinting below does wash out the other colors.

Comment: Cool. Maybe this time try to create a bridging header and use it as objective-c code.

Comment: @Opus1217 see the Edit to my answer which explains how to use it as Objective C code in swift.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using [How to tint a transparent PNG image in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514066/how-to-tint-a-transparent-png-image-in-iphone) to do the tinting, but that just darkened the red and black on the cards and left the white untouched. However, I switched to CGBlendMode of .Darken (instead of .Color) and that achieved that I was looking for - the white turns to the yellow color and the red/blacl is acceptably darkened also.