# UIImage PNG coloration

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uiimage

I would like to color a PNG when user clicks on it.

I found an example in Xcode [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514066/how-to-tint-a-transparent-png-image-in-iphone) but when I try it in C# I can't Retrieve the image.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
public UIImage DrawSelectedBorder(UIImage image)
{
    UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(image.Size, false, image.CurrentScale); // for correct resolution on retina, thanks @MobileVet
    CGContext context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();

    context.TranslateCTM(0, image.Size.Height);
    context.ScaleCTM((System.nfloat)1.0, (System.nfloat)(-1.0));

    CGRect rect = new CGRect(0, 0, image.Size.Width, image.Size.Height);

    context.SetBlendMode(CGBlendMode.Normal);
    context.SetFillColor(UIColor.Black.CGColor);
    context.FillRect(rect);


    // draw original image
    context.SetBlendMode(CGBlendMode.Normal);
    context.DrawImage(rect,image.CGImage);

    // tint image (losing alpha) - the luminosity of the original image is preserved
    context.SetBlendMode(CGBlendMode.Color);
    context.FillRect(rect);

    // mask by alpha values of original image
    context.SetBlendMode(CGBlendMode.DestinationIn);
    context.DrawImage(rect, image.CGImage);

    UIImage coloredImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

    return coloredImage;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tried your code. Everything is right but you didn't choose the color you want to fill in your PNG.

Change:

```
// tint image (losing alpha) - the luminosity of the original image is preserved
context.SetBlendMode(CGBlendMode.Color);
context.FillRect(rect);
```

to:

```
// tint image (losing alpha) - the luminosity of the original image is preserved
context.SetBlendMode(CGBlendMode.Color);
context.SetFillColor(UIColor.Red.CGColor);
context.FillRect(rect);
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it, i see something like `[tintColor setFill];` in original post but i was thinking that it's a comment.

Comment: It's not, original post don't show you that `tintColor` is a variable that set with an color. And to use it you have to call `SetFillColor` into context. So to use `tintColor` variable, you can init it like `CGColor tintColor = UIColor.Red.CGColor;` and then call `context.SetFillColor(tintColor);`