# iphone png file upside down

Tags: iphone, image, png

I'm trying to draw an image to the screen in a UIView subclass I'm making.

It's all working perfectly expect for the fact that my image is coming out upside down.

I'm using the code...

```
CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(rect);
CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(rect);
UIImage *thumbImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"single_blue" ofType:@"png"]];
CGImageRef thumbImageRef = thumbImage.CGImage;
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake((width/10)*[mean doubleValue] - 13, -3, 26, 35), thumbImageRef);
```

Any ideas why it's coming out upside down?

Thanks for any help.

Oliver

::EDIT:: OK, so Safari looks like it's died.  Chrome is working fine though.  Very odd.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506622/cgcontextdrawimage-draws-image-upside-down-when-passed-uiimage-cgimage

See here for fix.

Safari died and broke Stack Overflow so I couldn't search.  All better now though and found this :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iPhone CoreGraphics coordinate system is flipped upside-down from that of the Mac.
I often just vertically preflip all my images before adding them to my iPhone projects.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll be sure to do that in the future :D