# Iphone Mapkit : displaying a image on a map

Tags: ios, iphone, mapkit

I spent the evening trying to get a simple UIImage on a map.  I seen 2 Apple samples and one on github but they seem overly complex (one uses the Three20 network) and 2 out of 3 dont work in xcode 4.  Also one uses a bin file as its source.

Has anyone got a simple demo of a single image placed on a map.  I been looking at MKOverlay and MKOverlayView.

I been trying to follow
[iPhone MapKit: Custom MKPolygonView with image draws upside down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585563/iphone-mapkit-custom-mkpolygonview-with-image-draws-upside-down)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a traditional `MKAnnotationView` and set the `image` property. This is the right approach if the image should not be scaled when the mapView is scaled.