# Image drawing problem when using CGContext. Image is mirrored horizontally

Tags: iphone, drawing, uiimage, cgcontext

When I am drawing `UIImage* image` on UIView using the below code, the image is mirrored horizontally. It is like that if I draw 4, it is drawing like this [image] ..

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(x, y, imageWidth, imageHeight);
CGContextDrawImage((CGContextRef) g, rect, ((UIImage*)image).CGImage);
```

That is the problem??? I am doing wrong??? or if somebody know how to fix it, please let me also know. I very appreciate that in advance.

Thanks a loooooooooot.

Comment: It's mirroring vertically, not horizontally

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See: [CGContextDrawImage draws image upside down when passed UIImage.CGImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506622/cgcontextdrawimage-draws-image-upside-down-when-passed-uiimage-cgimage)

Use `[image drawInRect:rect]` instead of `CGContextDrawImage`.

Comment: `[image drawInRect:rect]` will only work if the context is the current graphics context - if it's not, you need to use the Core Graphics methods after all.

Comment: True enough, but for doing stuff on UIViews, this is pretty much all you need. Of course, I prefer just using UIImageViews.

Comment: I suggest using transformation as described in the latter answer in that question.

Answer (score 4):

you can turn the picture the right way around using

```
CGAffineTransform transform =CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, height);
transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);

//draw image in the context
CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, ((UIImage*)image).CGImage);
```

Using [image drawInRect:rect] uses the default context i.e. the screen, you can not give it your current context, e.g. if you want to put it as part of a button's ima