# Transform a CGRect in Core Graphic coordinates

Tags: ios, uiview, core-graphics

Is there a way to transform a `CGRect` with `UIView` system coordinates into Core Graphics coordinates, where the origin is in the lower-left corner?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506622/cgcontextdrawimage-draws-image-upside-down-when-passed-uiimage-cgimage/511199?s=1|0.0000#511199 uses the standard technique of moving to the height of the view and flipping the y-scale.  CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -imageRect.size.height);

Answer (score 1):

**Sure. You just have to subtract the y-origin and the height of the rect away from the view's height.**

```
rect.origin.y = view.frame.size.height-(rect.origin.y+rect.size.height)
```

You can represent this with a `CGAffineTransform` like so:

```
CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, view.size.height-((rect.origin.y*2.0)+rect.size.height))
```

You subtract the origin twice as you're now working with a relative value, instead of an absolute one.

---

However, if you only want to flip a context to work in `UIView` coordinates you'd want:

```
CGFloat ctxHeight = CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(c).size.height;
CGContextScaleCTM(c, 1, -1);
CGContextTranslateCTM(c, 0, -ctxHeight);
```

Comment: Do you know the method using the CGAffineTransform?