# How do I rotate objects before it is drawn within UIGraphicsImageRenderer?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

```
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 500, height: 500))
    let image = renderer.image { context in
        let size = renderer.format.bounds.size
        UIColor.red.setFill()
        context.cgContext.fillEllipse(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
        let x = 300 //center
        let y = 100 //center
        let w = 200
        let h = 60
        let r = 5.41 //radians
        UIColor.white.setFill()
        context.cgContext.fill(CGRect(x: x - w / 2, y: y - h / 2, width: w, height: h))
    }
```

The result is like this:

How can I rotate my white rectangle with rotation center in the middle of the rectangle before it is drawn in context?

[image]

Comment: Too late, you already drew it. There are no “drawn objects”, just pixels. And those pixels are now done. You should have transformed the context before you drew the white rectangle.

Comment: @matt, can I place there rotated rectangle instead?

Comment: Yes, of course. But you cannot rotate it _now_.

Comment: You are completely right, I changed my question.

Comment: Ok but you don’t rotate the rectangle. You rotate the context and draw the rectangle into it.

Comment: Ok, but what context? Because I need to rotate the context for object (here white rectangle), not for a whole UIImage (here red circle). Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, just as I said. You rotate the context in order to draw the rectangle.

Comment: After `context.cgContext.rotate(by: CGFloat(r))` my square disappeared. Why?

Comment: Because it rotates around its origin. So you need to translate the origin before and after the rotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rotate your context with the following api:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcontext/1456228-rotate

This is what it looks like for your example:

```
            // applied 5 rectangles to visualize the rotation origin.
            for i in 0...5 {
                let r: CGFloat = 0.1 * CGFloat(i) //radians
                context.cgContext.rotate(by: r)
                UIColor.white.setFill()
                context.cgContext.fill(CGRect(x: x - w / 2, y: y - h / 2, width: w, height: h))
            }
```

[image: example image]

Note that the rotation occurs around the context's origin. If you want a different center, you may need to apply a translation first (`translateBy(x:y:)` - see apple documentation for details).

Comment: Thank you for now, I am gonna check it and see how it works...;)

Comment: Oww, it worked perfectly... but when I draw UIImage, it is placed upside down. Why?

Comment: This may be unrelated - please create a new question and share your code.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/64538344/2303865

Comment: @Bartłomiej Semańczyk if this answers your question, please mark it as the accepted answer.